# Using monetdb_append from MonetdbLite C API

Tags: c, performance, monetdblite

I am trying to use MonetDBLite C in an application. According to the PDF (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08520.pdf), I would benefit from a boost in speed in loading massive amount of data using **monetdb_append** function. From PDF:

> In addition to issuing SQL queries, the embedded process can
>   efficiently bulk append large amounts of data to the database using
>   the monetdb_append function. This function takes the schema and the
>   name of a table to append to, and a reference to the data to append to
>   the columns of the table. This function allows for efficient bulk
>   insertions, as there is significant overhead involved in parsing
>   individual INSERT INTO statements, which becomes a bottleneck when the
>   user wants to insert a large amount of data.

This is the declaration in embedded.h

```
char* monetdb_append(monetdb_connection conn, const char* schema, const char* table, append_data *data, int ncols);
```

Has anybody an example how to use this function? I assume that **batid** of the  **append_data** structure is the identification of a BAT structure. But it is not clear how that can be used with the existing API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary append indeed requires construction of as many BAT structures as you have columns to append. Some additional MonetDBLite headers need to be included (`monetdb_config.h` and `gdk.h`). The important parts are:

1. Create the BATs using `COLnew` with the correct type and count
2. Add some values to them, e.g. by pointer access (of the correct type length) to `bat->theap.base[i]`
3. Set BAT properties (`BATsetcount`, `BATsettrivprop` and `BBPkeepref`) for the append
4. Allocate and populate the `append_data` data structure.
5. Call `monetdb_append`.

Below is a short example how to append 42 values to a one-column table containing integers (`CREATE TABLE test (my_column INTEGER);`)

```
// startup, connect etc. before

size_t n = 42;
BAT* b = COLnew(0, TYPE_int, n, TRANSIENT);
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ((int*)b->theap.base)[i] = i; // or whatever
}

BATsetcount(b, n);
BATsettrivprop(b);
BBPkeepref(b->batCacheid);

append_data *ad = NULL;
ad = malloc(1 * sizeof(append_data));
ad[0].colname = "my_column";
ad[0].batid = b->batCacheid;

if (monetdb_append(conn, "sys", "test", ad, 1) != NULL) { /* handle error */}
```

Comment: That looks very clear. For string types ((char *)b->theap.base)[i] = (char *)mydata; is enough? Are there any other hints for date, time, timestamp types that do not have a direct translation to counterpart C types?

Comment: You can use BATappend for non-native types