# Loading huge tables with `INSERT INTO test VALUES` in MonetDBLite

Tags: monetdblite

In my use case I'm generating data at runtime, and the cost of serializing such data into a CSV file and then loading to MonetDBLite using `COPY` will be potentially greater than using something like `INSERT INTO tablename VALUES`. Given that MonetDBLite does not use DBConnections as in ODBC/iODBC, does that mean that I do not need to clear the memory using explicit `COMMIT` statements, or do I still need to run `COMMIT` after loading some GB of data into a table in order not to occupy all the available primary memory? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which MonetDBLite are you using? You can use from-memory appends for very fast data loading in this case I think. For R/Python, we can directly append from data frames, for C the process is a little less convenient.

Comment: Yes, I'm using C, but I'm not necessairly looking for an easy solution, but for the most efficient for MonetDBLite-C. I'm using the one directly from the github repo. How can I use from-memory append in the current API?

Comment: Ok, I found your previous answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/52254589/1376095.